# jQuery.serialize outputting duplicate null values

Tags: jquery, ajax, serialization, form-submit

I have a form here like

```
<div id="contact" class="tab-pane fade"></br>
<form class="container" id="form" action="validate.php">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label style="color: #fff;" for="name">First Name:</label>
                <input style="color: #C0C0C0;" type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label style="color: #fff;" for="name">Last Name:</label>
                <input style="color: #C0C0C0;" type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label style="color: #fff;" for="subject">Subject:</label>
                <input style="color: #C0C0C0;" type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
                <label style="color: #fff;" for="email">Email Address:</label>
                <input style="color: #C0C0C0;" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label style="color: #fff;" for="comment">Your Message:</label>
      <textarea style="color: #C0C0C0;" class="form-control" rows="5" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Type in your message"></textarea>
    </div>
    </div></ br>
    <button role="button" type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">Send Message</button>
</form>
</div>
```

And in the javascript file I have this ajax code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    //Validate Form Start
    var form = $('form');

    form.submit(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation()
        console.log(form.serialize());

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: form.attr("action"),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            console.log("Email Sent.");
            $('#submit').html('Message Sent! Await response.');
            $('#submit').attr('class', 'btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block');
            function submitTimeout() {
                $('#submit').html('Send Another Message?');
                $('#submit').attr('class', 'btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block');
            }
            setTimeout(submitTimeout(), 3000);
            form.each(function(){
                this.reset();
                });
            }
        });
    });
    //Validate form end.

});
```

As you can see in the js when I log the `form.serialize();` to the console it gives me this with duplicated null values.

```
fname=afasw&lname=asd&subject=asf&%EF%BF%BDmail=fasafs%40easdfsf&message=safasff&fname=&email=&subject=&lname=&message=
```

I don't know why this is happening and I have searched everywhere but coudn't find a proper solution. Can anyone help me out.

Also on the other hand in the javascript code

```
function submitTimeout() {
            $('#submit').html('Send Another Message?');
            $('#submit').attr('class', 'btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block');
        }
        setTimeout(submitTimeout(), 3000);
```

It only changes the html but doesnt change back the attr also changes it instantly ignoring the 3000 ms timeout. Anything I did wrong?

Comment: try to reset the form after ajax success call function done..

Comment: I did reset tho.

Comment: You should target the ID of your form by $('#form') you are missing #,  and reset it by $('#forme')[0].reset();

Comment: for the timeout, you used it incorrectly. You call the function right away (and it does not return anything). So the setTimeout does nothing (it expects a function). It should be like this `setTimeout(submitTimeout, 3000);`

Comment: Thank you both ! That fixed the setTimeout problem . Yet i dont know why the serialize shows duplicated null values .

Comment: @GeninaAnneGabuten i declared a variable form on the top var form = $('form');

Comment: you are not targeting the id of the form right?

Comment: Yeah i'm not im targetting the form tag. It works tho.